# Assigning random material color

Tags: materials, color

I am trying to script a basic grid of cubes with different colors for each cube. Does each cube need its own “material” or can the diffuse color for a single material be changed for each cube?

In any event, I’m not sure how to assign the materials or the colors.

The basic grid of cubes looks like this:

```
import bpy

for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        location = (x*4, y*4, 0)
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location = location, scale = (1, 1, 1))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want to use python, you can use this script:

Explanation:

```
newMat = bpy.data.materials.new(name = 'Material')
```

This just creates a new material with name "Material". Is is not used by an object right now.

```
object.data.materials.append(newMat)
```

This appends the materials to the object's data.

```
newMat.use_nodes = True
```

This tells the material to use nodes (instead of being a "pure" color).

```
nodes = newMat.node_tree.nodes
```

With this the variable nodes gets access to the nodeTree/nodes (this is basically what you see in the shader editor).

```
material_output = nodes.get("Material Output")
```

Here i get the material output node.

[image]

```
node_emission = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse')
```

Creates a new Diffuse node

[image]

```
node_emission.inputs[0].default_value = (random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1),1)
```

Sets the color to the diffuse node. The inputs array represents all incoming values. Default value is the value/color in this case.

```
links = newMat.node_tree.links
```

Gets access to the links

```
newLink = links.new(node_emission.outputs[0], material_output.inputs[0])
```

Creates the link between your diffuse and material output

```
import bpy 
import random
 
def createRandomMat(object):
    
    newMat = bpy.data.materials.new(name = 'Material')
    object.data.materials.append(newMat)

    newMat.use_nodes = True

    nodes = newMat.node_tree.nodes

    material_output = nodes.get("Material Output")

    node_emission = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse')

    node_emission.inputs[0].default_value = (random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1),random.uniform(0, 1),1) 

    links = newMat.node_tree.links

    newLink = links.new(node_emission.outputs[0], material_output.inputs[0])
    
   

for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        location = (x*4, y*4, 0)
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location = location, scale = (1, 1, 1))
        
        object = bpy.context.active_object
        
        createRandomMat(object)
```

result:

[image]

material created:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You could use the object info node and connect the random output to a color ramp, as shown on [this page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/object_info.html)

[image]

[image]

Comment: is this is in "cycles"? is there a way to do it as text?

Comment: @vpo text might need Geometry -> random per island