# Auto apply different material on each objects

Tags: materials

Let's say I have a lot of different objects in the scene, over 1000, is there a way to automatically give each of them a different material? I need to get different colors on id map

Comment: Hello, could you please elaborate, tell what kind of object, what kind of material, etc?

Comment: This sounds like the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), What exactly are you trying to achieve? There are multiple ways to get different colors on objects that don't involve thousands of materials, like cryptomates or random color materials

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I need different materials so that when baking ID maps, there are different colors on the maps so that I can conveniently texture the model in the Substance Painter

Comment: I have always manually assigned the material to each object, and thus got what I need, but in this situation I have more than 1000 objects, and I think it will take a very long time. so I wanted to make sure if there could be a way to automate this process.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/233856/assigning-random-material-color
The answer contains a very detailed process of how to accomplish this using python scripting to automate the whole thing